# How to login into Google Cloud serial console? (Debian 10 Buster image)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, debian, login-script

I've succesfully broke my SSH config by performing some updates and the service fails to launch. I've managed to turn on the serial console for my project and VM and tried to follow this tutorial on how to access it interactively: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console#connectserialconsole . In order to be able to log-in, I am using the following start up script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
adduser local
echo local:localpass | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers local
```

However when I go into serial console - Serial port 1 I am greeted with a bunch of logs and when I try to enter the user `local` as username I always get `Login incorrect` message displayed. My suspision is that the login script does not even get executed as I've tried to issued other stuff like disabling and stopping services with no effect. Anyone has experience with something similar?

Comment: Does the instance have a user with the name **local**? Look at the boot logs to check for boot problems. I wrote an article that has a section on mounting one system's boot disk on another system for repair: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: thanks for the response! I was examining the boot logs and it turns out like this error is causing the ssh.service to fail. `May  5 13:23:29 machine sshd[24791]: /usr/sbin/sshd: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Probably by reinstalling the SSH server. At this point, I recommend creating a new VM, snapshotting the original VM's disk, creating a new disk from the snapshot, and mounting it on the new VM. Then copy your data to the new VM.